# Setting accessibilityLabel for UITableView header text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiaccessibility

I am trying to find a way to set `accessibilityLabel` for my tableview's header text.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {        
    return @"Table View Header";
}
```

In my case, my accessibility label is different from the returned tableview's header text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `accessibilityLabel` property, **write the text in the definition of the header view itself** as I did in the code snippet hereunder by adding an accessibility element:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    CGRect headerViewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tableView.frame.size.width, 44.0);
    UIView * headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerViewFrame];

    UILabel * headerViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerViewFrame];
    headerViewLabel.text = @"Table View Header";
    [headerView addSubview: headerViewLabel];

    UIAccessibilityElement * a11yHeader = [[UIAccessibilityElement alloc] initWithAccessibilityContainer:headerView];
    a11yHeader.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = headerView.frame;
    a11yHeader.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    a11yHeader.accessibilityLabel = @"my new header text for accessibility";
    a11yHeader.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitHeader;

    headerView.accessibilityElements = @[a11yHeader];

    return headerView;
}
```

Try this out and adapt it to your application.

Not that easy to go back to ObjC  but, now, you can **set accessibilityLabel for UITableView header text** by following this rationale.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could also use the `textLabel` property of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

Code example:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] init];
    headerView.textLabel.text = @"tableview header";
    headerView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    headerView.accessibilityLabel = @"tableview header for accessibility";

    return headerView;
}
```